# Like in the following React code, JavaScript can not be placed directly within JSX, but why can JSX be placed within JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

A few days ago I asked about placing JS within JSX. However, I would like to ask about the reverse here. Is it possible to place JSX within JavaScript? Apparently, it does work, as in the following code... But I am confused about why!

```
return (
    // comments work here, outside of the `<div></div>` segment

    <div className="contact-card">
      <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150" alt="profile" />
      <div className="user-details">
        <p>Name: Jenny Han</p>
        <p>Email: Jenny.Han@notreal.com</p>

        {
          // But within this `<div></div>` segment,
          // JavaScript has to be enclosed within `{}`

          // So this is a JavaScript segment now,
          // But why does `<p>Age: 25</p>` JSX work here?
          showAge && <p>Age: 25</p>
        }

      </div>
    </div>

    // Comments work here too!
  );
};
```

Comment: When the compiler sees a `<component/element>` It recognizes it as JSX regardless of where it is.

Comment: This is a good read: https://babeljs.io/docs/en/

Comment: @95faf8e76605e973 Lol. Sure, thanks! You have a nice day too.

Comment: You are welcome. I sense sarcasm though haha. By default react does not really come with babel but majority of apps incorporate it, one of which is create-react-app

Comment: @95faf8e76605e973 So, I guess what you are trying to say is that babel makes JSX within JS possible. Thanks.

Comment: Yes, a good example is if you pull up the stack snippets here when you try to post an answer or question. Try to include the react scripts via cdn. They have the "use babel / es2015" checkbox on the left panel. try to use JSX without it, the console will return errors

Comment: Got it! Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://reactjs.org/docs/introducing-jsx.html

> ### Embedding Expressions in JSX
>
> You can put any valid JavaScript expression inside the curly braces in JSX
>
> ### JSX is an Expression Too
>
> After compilation, JSX expressions become regular JavaScript function calls and evaluate to JavaScript objects.
>
> This means that you can use JSX inside of if statements and for loops, assign it to variables, accept it as arguments, and return it from functions

In other words, you can include JSX directly within JS and JS within JSX (as long as the JS is enclosed within braces), and so on.

Comment: Thank you for posting that @LionelRowe. Although, I was thrown a little towards the end. "you can recursively include JSX inside JS inside JSX, and so on", sounds like you can place JSX within JS and JS within JSX on equal footing... However, that's not true. You can apparently place JSX directly within JS, but you can't do JS within JSX unless you use the enclosing braces.

Answer (score 0):

As I mentioned in my comment, this is the work of JavaScript compilers (or transpiler - whichever you prefer) such as [Babel](https://babeljs.io/). For example in Babel, in their website you can see a sample of how they transform your JSX source code into JavaScript that the browser engines can understand. That is why JSX works within JS

[image]

The transforming of the code is necessary because browser engines by default does not understand your JSX. As stated in the [JSX Specifications](https://facebook.github.io/jsx/):

> JSX is NOT intended to be implemented by engines or browsers. It's NOT a
> proposal to incorporate JSX into the ECMAScript spec itself.

[JSX is an expression too](https://reactjs.org/docs/introducing-jsx.html#jsx-is-an-expression-too) so that is why it immediately works in your example above.

Expressions: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expression_(computer_science)

Here is its syntax: https://facebook.github.io/jsx/#syntax

```js
function App(){

  const sampleRetExpression = () => { return "yo" };

  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      {true && <div>Hello, world!</div>}
      {true && 101}
      {true && sampleRetExpression()}
    </React.Fragment>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(<App/>, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
<div id="other"></div>
```